# Excel - Two way lookup, where the second dimension depends upon the first dimension

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to figure out a way to do the following two way lookup.

I have two values to lookup, a subject, lets say "Maths" and then a numerical value, say 6.5

I wish to lookup these values in the table below, where I want an exact match for the Subject, and then in that specific row, I wish to find the first value exceeding my numerical value (the values in each row only increase). An example of my table I wish to lookup the value for is below:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Art | 0.00 | 3.67 | 6.2 | 7.8 |
| History | 3.78 | 6.21 | 7.2 | 9.8 |
| Maths | 5.6 | 6.3 | 6.6 | 8.9 |

So for example, for my input Maths, 6.5, I wish for the output to be 6.6, and for Art/3.6, I wish for the output to be 3.67 etc.

Thanks!

Internet research; I've got single row lookups working, but struggling to generalise it into a two dimensional lookup based upon the text search before the number search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Excel 2010, try the following, assuming your values for each subject are sorted ascending as shown in your example:

```
=INDEX(
    INDEX(
        $B$1:$E$3,
        MATCH($H1, $A$1:$A$3, 0),
        5 - COLUMN(INDEX($1:$1, 1):INDEX($1:$1, 4))
    ),
    1,
    MATCH(
        $I1,
        INDEX(
            $B$1:$E$3,
            MATCH($H1, $A$1:$A$3, 0),
            5 - COLUMN(INDEX($1:$1, 1):INDEX($1:$1, 4))
        ),
        -1
    )
)
```

[image]

If this returns an error, it may need to be entered as an **array formula**.

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}`around the formula.

Or it may need to be array-entered with the array of columns embedded in an `IF` for reasons which are obscure:

```
=INDEX(
    INDEX(
        $B$1:$E$3,
        MATCH($H1, $A$1:$A$3, 0),
        IF(1, 5 - COLUMN(INDEX($1:$1, 1):INDEX($1:$1, 4)))
    ),
    1,
    MATCH(
        $I1,
        INDEX(
            $B$1:$E$3,
            MATCH($H1, $A$1:$A$3, 0),
            IF(1, 5 - COLUMN(INDEX($1:$1, 1):INDEX($1:$1, 4)))
        ),
        -1
    )
)
```

If it still doesn't work, post back with the error and the result.

In `365` the formula can be shortened to:

```
=LET(
    rng, $A$1:$E$3,
    rw, FILTER(rng, TAKE(rng, , 1) = $H1),
    XLOOKUP($I1, rw, rw, , 1)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked! And some more excel formulae for me to learn how to use in general! (The 365 method is the one I used; not sure why the 2010 tag came up, I clicked a different one, which I've changed it with now!)

Answer (score 1):

Formula below may help you. Type Input1 to F column, Input2 to G column. And paste formula below to H column. Output will be what you expected.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$4,MATCH($F$1,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($C$2:$E$4>=G1, MATCH($F$1,$A$2:$A$4,0),0),0)+1)
```

Comment: Thankyou for this; it has been of great value, and has the added adaptability of being able to find a value, then use the value 0, 1, 2, etc placed to the right of it (which I also needed to do (specifically, 0,1,22,23))